# Agreement and possessive genitive

Tags: classical-latin, sentence-translation, syntax, genitive, grammarians

What we do in the following example?

I need to combine two words in a phrase: 'professional' and 'holiday'.

There is no adjective 'professional' in Latin or my searching is bad. So I can use the genitive of 'profession' - *professionis*.

I get: festum (nom.) professionis (gen.), and there is no problem yet (and all agree too that there is no problem in the following combination: - "canis pueri boni"). But if I need to use a verb which governs words by special cases - there seems to be a little trouble.

*Professionis* is not a true adjective, but this is different from an *appositive getitive* example (I think) - so what we need to do!?

"Congratulor" takes the accusative, so "festum" must be in this case. But what about *professionis*?

I can't make them agree.

Answer (score 4):

You decline the main noun and keep the genetive of the other noun.

- A relationship by marriage is: *affinitas*.
- A relationship by marriage with a very good man is: *affinitas viri optimi*.
- I congratulate you on your relationship by marriage with a very good man is: *Gratulor tibi affinitatem viri […] optimi* ([Cicero, Epistulae ad familiares, 8,13](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam8.shtml#13)); overly literal translation – what he's actually saying is: “Congratulations on an excellent son-in-law.” (The interjection *medius fidius* means something like “on my word,” it refers to a god called [Dius Fidius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dius_Fidius).)

Comment: Thanks! I do in such way before I asked my question, but it was only on the basis of my own language perception, not on the basis of examples from Classics.